# Can a function have a set as argument or value?

Tags: functions

I was joking with someone when I spelled some proper noun in a mathematical equation:
$$\tan x \in f(u)$$
Obviously this function needs to have a value that is a set in order to make sense. Hence, this got me thinking: can a function have sets as argument or value?

For example maybe there could be a function so that $f(x)=\mathbb{R}^x$, or perhaps $f(\mathbb{R}^x) = x$ or even a function that adds one to each of the elements of the argument set $f([0,\infty)) = [1,\infty)$.

Can such functions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set valued functions are studied in convex analysis and convex optimization. The subdifferential of a convex function is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

A subset $U$ of some set $X$ is an element of the power set of $X$, and there is no reason that a function (it would maybe called a map in this case) cannot have values in the power set of a set.